# how to correct use 'and if' in JPQL, Like this: @Query("select t from tablename t where 1=1 and if(:a='', 1=1,t.a =:a) ") ,

Tags: jpa

how to correct use 'and if' in JPQL, Like this:

```
@Query("select  t  from tablename t where 1=1 and if(:a='', 1=1,t.a =:a) ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no if in JPQL.

You could try something like this:

```
select t from tablename t 
where (:a = '' or t.a = :a)
```

But the best way would be to have to separate methods on the Repo:

```
// 1.

@Query("select t from tablename t where t.a =:a") 

// 2.

@Query("select t from tablename t")
```

The 2. can be implemented generic because it's a simple findAll